# Apache mod_rewrite rule to hide URI part

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to cut some part of URI, but I still need to pass it internally.

Ex: www.hostname.com/category/N-abcdef

To: www.hostname.com/category

But I need internally to do a redirect passing N-abcdef

If I put these rules, it work:

```
RewriteRule ^/category/N-abcdef$ /category [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/category$ /category/N-abcdef [PT]
```

But I was trying to do something more generic, because the N-.* is different for each category. I've tried these:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/(N-.*)/?$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(N-.*)/?$ /$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1/%2 [PT]
```

These rules even remove the desired part (N-.*), But does not make the internal redirect correctly, as the reported result is not desirable.

In short, I need to hide the N-FOO URI.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can not catch `N-FOO` once you've discarded it and redirected the URL.

Comment: I hope that was a way to do that, the problem is that N-FOO is dynamic.

Comment: You can put it in an environment variable when you do the first redirection. I'd advise against that though.

Comment: @hjpotter92, thanks for your reply! I've told here that was not possible, I think if I use env variable it could lose reference in high traffic, I dont know a way to turn these in more friendly url.